# Getting socket create,accept callback

Tags: winapi, networking, driver, winsock2, wfp

I am trying to get process id of the client which initiated a connection to the remote system/website.

Is it possible to write wfp driver which gets a callback for socket create/accept event! if not through wfp, what are the other options available?

Comment: There is no API that I'm aware of for what you are asking for. You will likely have to poll the info manually, such as with [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcptable2) or [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getextendedtcptable)

Comment: Thanks, Remy for the reply. GetTcpTable2 is giving the details I am looking for. The only problem is its size and need parsing of all row till I get the matching

Comment: This is possible with WFP, but can be more difficult to implement. Because the PID at the time of accept callback on WFP is not the PID of the receiving process. This is because the context at that point is an arbitrary thread context.
To solve this problem, it is necessary to map and manage the PID and port of IN / OUT bound. Annoying work is required.